# _.isEqual reporting a difference when there is none

Tags: lodash

I am trying to compare two objects using the `.isEqual` method from lodash-node package. Even though the objects are same, `.isEqual` returns `false`.

```js
var _ = require('lodash-node');

var obj1 = {"properties":{"property":[{"comfort":["2.4 GHz"]},{"name":["Mosaic"]}]}};
var obj2 = {"properties":{"property":[{"name":["Mosaic"]},{"comfort":["2.4 GHz"]}]}};

if(_.isEqual(obj1, obj2)) //--> Returns false
    console.log('same')
else
    console.log('not same');
```

node:- v0.12.7
lodash-node:- v3.10.1

The objects look similar to me. Please help in pointing out if there is any difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The objects are not equal since even when deep-comparing, an array is an ordered collection, and order matters. Your array holds the same values, but not at the same order.

Comment: Ah, right. I missed that. Let me sort the arrays before doing a deep comparison. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

I realise this doesn't apply in your example but I found another case where lodash returns not equal for objects where `JSON.stringify` returns the same string.

In my case, one object had a property with the value `undefined` whereas the other object did not have that property at all.

Personally, I'd argue lodash is incorrect in this case but it's a bit subjective.

Answer (score 6):

The order in an array matters, so

```
_.isEqual([1,2], [2, 1]) === false
```

which is why your example returns false.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I missed that bit.